# Initializing pointer or reference member variable to point to another member

Tags: c++

Is the following well defined behaviour, and does it behave as one would expect:

```cpp
class A {
    int x;
    int &y = x;
    int *z = &x;
}
```

<s>Additionally, is there anything that I have to be careful of when doing something similar?</s> (see update) Is it important that y comes after x?

Can I do it with an array like so:

```cpp
class A {
    int arr[2];
    int &y = arr[0];
    int *z = &(arr[1]);
}
```

All of this seems to [work fine](http://ideone.com/Wvkd3x), but I'm concerned that this is implementation dependent/not portable.

**Edit/Update**

I was using this to replace a group of member variables with an array, while maintaining backwards compatibility. So, I'm going from something like this:

```cpp
class A {
    int x0;
    int x1;
}
```

to

```cpp
class A {
    int x[2];
    int &x0 = x[0];
    int &x1 = x[1];
}
```

Since asking this question, I have come across an example of something to be wary of when using it like this: `x0` and `x1` do not behave the same as before if they appear in initializer lists. They cannot be initialized to an integer literal, and if they are initialized to anything at all, `x0` will not refer to `x[0]` and/or `x1` will not refer to `x[1]`.

I would post this as an answer, but I still don't know the answer to my main question: Are any of the given scenarios implementation dependent/undefined behaviour?

Comment: "behave as one would expect:" - that depends on what you expect :)

Comment: ideone is a poor site because it suppresses compiler warnings  , which makes a fateful combination with the fact that major compilers report "warning" for a lot of ill-formed and otherwise erroneous code .

Comment: Is there a reason why you actually want to do this? Yes, the code is valid, but it is obfuscated and you (or any other programmer that comes along) will spend cycles trying to figure out what the code is doing.

Comment: If you want to do this, I recommend you give the variables names which clarify what they are, i.e. `arr`, `arr_begin_ref`, `arr_ptr`. Also, beware to maintain const correctness when aliasing variables. I have seen many instances of this pattern being used to subvert const-ness.

Comment: @M.M I've updated the question with some additional information, which includes enough context to determine what I was expecting behaviour-wise. However, I'm no longer interested in behavioural differences.

Comment: It's well-defined but still not clear what you "expect". I of course would expect that if you initialize a class member to something else, then the default initializer is not applied

Comment: You also lose the ability to do class assignment,  and the default copy constructor might not do what you expect  (the new object's reference members will refer to the old object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this all works, and it doesn’t matter what order they come in (unless you try to “take the address of” an uninitialized reference, since that depends on its “value”).  Even with an array, mere pointer arithmetic is [well-defined](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6).